# How to change class name of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have four buttons like this

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button id="btn-men"  class="btn btn-default active" 
             i18n:translate="men">Men</button>
  <button id="btn-women" class="btn btn-default" i18n:translate="women">Women</button>
  <button id="btn-kids" class="btn btn-default" i18n:translate="kids">Kids</button>
 </div>
```

And I have different css styles for the class  "btn btn-default active" and "btn btn-default". what I want to know is if there is any way of changing the class name of the clicked button as *btn btn-default* active from *btn btn-default* and also change the unclicked button as *btn btn-default* during run time.

I also use i18n for mulitilingual purpose.

Comment: Yes, there is a way, or many ways. What have you tried?

Comment: It looks like you are using bootstrap, which handles the active class all by itself when you click on the other buttons.

Comment: @@Eugen Timm: Your absolutely right.

Comment: @@Eugen Timm: How can i stop the active class to call itself when i click on the other buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using bootstrap, so solve it using bootstrap way

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label id="btn-men" class="btn btn-default active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" checked /> Men
    </label>
    <label id="btn-women" class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"/> Women
    </label>
    <label id="btn-kids" class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"/> Kids
    </label>
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9x1bpuLo/)

Look at the radio example under [bootstrap buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons)

Comment: @@Arun P Johny : It works. But it creates another problem for me. Now If i use i18n: translate then it doesnt work.

Comment: @stackOverFlow try `<input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"/> <span i18n:translate="kids">Kids</span>`

Comment: @@Arun P Johny : Thank you so so so much. It worked as i expected.

Answer (score 5):

Use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` for this purpose

```
$(".btn-default").click(function() {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/371/)